# Como hago para que mi menu no se vea ocultarse al achicar la pantalla (responsive)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, responsive

estoy creando una pagina para practicar y me encontre con algo que me gustaria resolver y es la barra de navegacion estilo hamburguesa que cuando la quiero hacer responsive esta funciona bien pero al achicarse se ve la animacion de como se oculta, es decir de como pasa de ser una barra superior a ser un menu oculto, como podria quitar esa animacion?, sin perder justamente las animaciones a la hora de presionar el boton. Adjunto fotos [image: en esta foto se puede ver cuando achico que esta la barra superior]
[image: y en esta otra foto se puede ver el "frame" donde se oculta, aclaro que se oculta completamente, lo que quiero resolver es que no se vea esa accion, sin perder las animaciones]

Comment: en la imagen 1 se puede ver como esta la barra superior, luego en la foto 2 se ve como se oculta al achicar ( quiero aclarar que se oculta por completo lo que quiero resolver es que no se vea esta accion sin perder las animaciones)

Comment: Adjunta tu código HTML y CSS que tengas echo para poder ayudarte mejor...